# Independent Date Dimension connected to a cube

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

I would like to answers to one business requirements.

I create a cube that models the following event : a customer send a product from an agency to another customer who receives it in another agency.

So I have a fact table with only two measures

- Amount
- Count

which is connected to these dimensions

- Product
- Sending Date
- Receiving Date
- Sender (Customer)
- Receiver (Customer)
- Sender (Agency)
- Receiver (Agency)

The users would like to analyse the following KPI, at a specific date :

- Number of transactions sent, the amount
- Number of transactions received, the amount
- Number of transactions pending, the amount

To answer this business requirement, I have added a new date dimension in the cube with no relation, so that the user can select a date from this independent dimension and get the different KPIs.

But I don't get any results.

Is it a good model ? How to make it possible for the user to use the independent Date Dimension to perform analyzes of different KPI ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement a role playing dimension http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3117/defining-role-playing-dimensions-for-sql-server-analysis-services/

Comment: Thanks. But don't think so because the role playing dimension have already been implemented hence Sending Date, Receiving Date, etc.. They have already been implemented. Now I would like to had a new Date dimension which will not be bound with the cube such that I could use this new dimension to answer to the business requirements.

Comment: Why are you making the new date dimension with no relation to the cube?   I don't understand what you are trying achieve with this.

Comment: If an user wants to analyse the KPI enumerated just by choosing a date from a date dimension, it is must choose a date from [Sending Date Dimension] to have [Number of transaction sent] KPI,choose a date from [Receiving Date Dimension] to have [Number of transaction received] KPI, what about [Number of pending transaction] KPI that is function of [Sending Date Dimension] and [Receiving Date Dimension]? How could I give the possibility to just choose one date from a date dimension not being from [Sending Date Dimension] or [Receiving Date Dimension] to have his KPI? @TabAlleman

Comment: So I think that having an independent date dimension will the good idea . From this dimension the user will choose his date an have his KPI. Very very simple like this, I think :) . @mmarie

Comment: Can you confirm you are building a multidimensional model (not tabular)? Also, does pending mean that the date chosen is in between the send date and the received date?

Comment: Maybe `LinkMember` as e. g. proposed in my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060872/calculating-a-rate-based-on-two-date-dimension-in-one-cube will help you solve your requirement?

Comment: @mmarie yes ! the user have to select a date, only one date neither from [Receiving Date Dimension] nor [Sending Date Dimension], to have the result.

Comment: I typically handle that requirement by making a daily snapshot table/view with a row for each day that the transaction is process. Then I bring that into the cube and tie it to the date dimension.

Comment: Thank you @FrankPl. It solves my problem. Now I would like to generalize the solution. In the new member I created, I use only one attribute (Date) of the date dimension, so when the user select the Month attribute there is no aggregation so the result it isn't good. How could I generalize the comparison between the two date dimension? Something like ([Measures].[Number of Transactions], [Time].[All],LINKMEMBER([Time].CurrentAttribute, [Dim Date Sending]) Instead of ([Measures].[Number of Transactions],[Time].[Date].[All],LINKMEMBER([Time].[Date].CurrentMember, [Dim Date Sending].[Date])) Thks

Comment: @FrankPl is it possible to use LinkMember with comparaison operator   something like [Dim Date Sending].[Date] < [Time].[Date].CurrentMember ?

Comment: @user3452538 Not this way. You could evaluate the relationship in one hierarchy, and then link that result to the other. But I think this would only be possible for single members, not for sets (like all dates less than a certain date).

Comment: @user3452538 Regarding the generalization: If you use a date **user hierarchy** instead of single date **attribute hierarchies**, you only use one hierarchy, but can link to all levels of it, whichever the user selected.

Comment: thanks all .... I found this article http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date/ that explain my problem and give a solution ...